# How can I capitalize the first letter of a string in Python, ignoring HTML tags?

Tags: python, django, string, uppercase

I would like to capitalize the first letter of a string, ignoring HTML tags. For instance:

```
<a href="google.com">hello world</a>
```

should become:

```
<a href="google.com">Hello world</a>
```

I wrote the following, which works, but it seems inefficient, since every character of the string is being copied to the output. Is there a better way to do it?

```
@register.filter
def capinit(value):
  gotOne = False
  inTag = False
  outValue = ''
  for c in value:
    cc = c
    if c == '<':
      inTag = True
    if c == '>':
      inTag = False
    if not inTag:
      if c.isalpha() or c.isdigit():
        if not gotOne:
          cc = c.upper()
        gotOne = True
    outValue = outValue + cc
  return outValue
```

Note that this ignores initial punctuation. It will capitalize the first letter it finds, unless it finds a number first in which case it doesn't capitalize anything.

Comment: Strings aren't mutable, so any solution will involve some copying anyway.

Comment: You might want to use `if...elif` so that it does not compute all the conditions every time.

Comment: Don't know why you don't use [string capitalize](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-capitalize-python/) since it already existed in python, just need to create a custom filter in django and take the input as 'Hello World' or anything in the template

Comment: Thanks but template filters such as capitalize or capfirst do not work because of the html tags.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do what you wanted:

```
html = '<a href="google.com">hello world</a>'

afterletter = None
dontcapital = 0
afterhtml = ""
for character in html:
    if character == "/" and afterletter == "<":
        afterhtml += character
        dontcapital = 1
    elif afterletter == ">":
        if dontcapital == 0:
            afterhtml += character.upper()
        else:
            afterhtml += character
            dontcapital = 0
    else:
        afterhtml += character
    afterletter = character

print(afterhtml)

#afterhtml is the output!
```

this should work from all the tests i did.
if anyone wants to work on it you can.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty similar to my solution. For efficiency, I was hoping for something that didn't loop through every character.

Comment: i not sure if it is possible to not loop through every character because it needs to know whether it is after a tag. for efficiency i don't think it would be noticable, i tested it with some html i made a while before that was about 600 lines and it took just as long as 1 line of html.